# How to make a rest call from react js

Tags: rest, reactjs

### React Code

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/ulearn/rest/course/getAll')
        .then(result=> {
            this.setState({items:result.json()});
        });}
```

When i tried making a rest api call from two different ports(react port is running on 8088 and my rest api  port running on 8080) i get the [following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMhRU.png)

Comment: And of course, you are scared to do very basic googling to find out what CORS is and how to do it properly? Instead you take screenshot and post one more pointless question. Google your error first it would save you tons of time.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with React, but as the message in the console explains, a problem with [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) :

> Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows
>   restricted resources (e.g. fonts) on a web page to be requested from
>   another domain outside the domain from which the resource
>   originated.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) A web page may freely embed images, stylesheets,
>   scripts, iframes, videos.[2] Certain "cross-domain" requests, notably
>   AJAX requests, however are forbidden by default by the same-origin
>   security policy.

You should setup CORS on http://localhost:8080.

Comment: `mode: 'no-cors' ` won't solve it anyway.

Comment: oh yeah... indeed... that will be an opaque response... I'm editing my answer :)

Comment: yes, they need to set up remote server

Comment: how do i fix this ???